# Incrementing counter within a text labeled button (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I would like to increment the count for each of these buttons individually. I know that the .find jquery function would come in handy. However my buttons are not incrementing

i.e. 
"You clicked me: 100 times"
"You clicked me: 22 times"
"You clicked me: 71 times"

```js
$('#target').on('click', function() {
  var numoftimes = parseInt($(this).find('span').html());
  $(this).find('span').html(numoftimes + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="target" type="button">You clicked me: <span>0</span>times</button>
<button id="target" type="button">You clicked me: <span>0</span>times</button>
<button id="target" type="button">You clicked me: <span>0</span>times</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute *id* should be unique in a document, use *class* instead. Also I will suggest you to use `.text()` instead of `.html()` when dealing with text only content:

```js
$('.target').on('click', function(){
  var numoftimes = parseInt( $(this).find('span').text());
  $(this).find('span').text(numoftimes + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="target" type="button">You clicked me: <span>0</span>times</button>
<button class="target" type="button">You clicked me: <span>0</span>times</button>
<button class="target" type="button">You clicked me: <span>0</span>times</button>
```

Comment: Should have known it was the .text vs .html scan that threw me off. Exactly what I was looking for. A million thanks!

Comment: @NanoNet, you are most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use class and not ID. ID needs to be unique

```js
$('.target').on('click', function() {
  var numoftimes = parseInt($(this).find('span').html()); // or .text()
  $(this).find('span').html(numoftimes + 1); // or .text()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="target" type="button">You clicked me: <span>0</span>times</button>
<button class="target" type="button">You clicked me: <span>0</span>times</button>
<button class="target" type="button">You clicked me: <span>0</span>times</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using id which has to be unique for every element so you can define class which can be common and can be used for the same

```
$('.target').on('click', function() {
  var numoftimes = parseInt($(this).find('span').html());
  $(this).find('span').html(numoftimes + 1);
});
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="target" class="target" type="button">You clicked me: <span>0</span>times</button>
<button id="target1" class="target" type="button">You clicked me: <span>0</span>times</button>
<button id="target2" class="target" type="button">You clicked me: <span>0</span>times</button>
```